# What does it mean to add a dependency to something in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I just met an error while working on my project and it was suggested by Android Studio to add dependency on `FileProvider.getUriForFile`. It resolved the error, but I do not know what it did. What does it mean to add a dependency?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Adding dependency in Android Studio is just like importing in other languages like in python/java. So it just depends on that specific function or class. The Gradle build system in Android Studio makes it easy to include external binaries or other library modules to your build as dependencies. The dependencies can be located on your machine or in a remote repository, and any transitive dependencies they declare are automatically included as well.

You can see the [Add Build Dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) for more details.